# Looking for a collection of tools for academic presentations

Tags: graphics, pdf, presentations, markdown, powerpoint

I would like to take my presentations and automatically produce all of the following.

Presentations include:

- Text
- Graphics

  - with captions
- Discussion Questions

  - with answers
- Links

I would like to produce

- PDF presentation
- PowerPoint presentation
- Text-only notes
- [Cloze Notes](http://classroom.synonym.com/make-cloze-passage-4425024.html) (procedurally generated)

It would also be nice (but not necessary) to produce

- Google slides presentation
- Presentations that have discussion questions but not answers
- A folder or presentation with graphics alone
- Mathematical equations on slides

I would like to produce the source presentation in markdown, but that isn't necessary. I have some scripting experience and don't mind editing scripts or stringing together all these processes, I just don't want to spend more time on scripting than I will on the presentations themselves.

I know PDFs can be made with pandoc and/or beamer, but as far as I know, it can't do anything else I am trying to accomplish. Any suggestion to accomplish all or part of the above is appreciated.

Comment: All that you mention is at least possible in `beamer`, with more or less difficulty. Now, *powerpoint* presentation are made by Microsoft PowerPoint, which is a proprietary program... so forget about it. At least with LaTeX and friend.

Comment: OK, I'll dig into beamer and make sure it can do everything I want. I know what you mean about PowerPoint, but I thought there might be some tools available, considering pptx is an open format.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of [SlideMight](http://www.slidemight.com), a data merge tool for PowerPoint. I had in mind to provide similar functionality as you list here, but it is not there yet.

Probably adding support for Markdown will bring SlideMight in the right direction, but full Markdown support will be a too big investment. Could you indicate what parts of Markdown you would need? SlideMight already supports data driven table population, so I would hope you wouldn't need that part of Markdown.